# Repeating outputs in Python

Tags: python

This code keep repeating the same sets of numbers that add up to a specific number. ex: 31+ 69 = 100. This will be repeated many times among other possibilities. What's the matter with my code ? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvLOY.png)

Thanks. Here it is:

```
import random

target_number = int(input('Input a number and we will return a list of two numbers that equate to this number'))

r1 = range(1,target_number)
r2 = range(1,target_number)

while True:
    for i in range(24):
        num1 = random.choice(r1)
        num2 = random.choice(r2)
        if num1 + num2 == target_number:
            print(f"solved: {num1}+{num2} = {target_number}")
```

Comment: What's the `for i in range(24)` for? Do you want to print 24 pairs of numbers?

Comment: The outer `while True` loop has no way to exit.  So it will run forever.  What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Using random numbers is highly inefficient. You might quickly get unique pairs in the beginning, but it will get increasingly harder to get **all** pairs. You want to generate **combinations**

Comment: You could set `num1` to be random and just make `num2 = target - num1`...

Comment: Yes, that was my also my comment to one of the answers ;)

Comment: If you want to pick some numbers (or combinations) at random, but not all, you may want to check [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 1):

As noted by HuLu, while True will run forever. The for loop with i could be removed as follows:

```
import random

target_number = int(input('Input a number and we will return a list of two numbers that equate to this number'))

r1 = range(1,target_number)
r2 = range(1,target_number)

while True:
    num1 = random.choice(r1)
    num2 = random.choice(r2)
    if num1 + num2 == target_number:
        print(f"solved: {num1}+{num2} = {target_number}")
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to find **all pairs that add up to your number**, try the following:

```
def find_factors(x):
    for i in range(x): # loop through all numbers (until x)
        if i <= x-i: # this is to avoid printing duplicate pairs, e.g. (2,3) and (3,2)
            print([i,x-i]) # print i, and i subtracted from x
```

This function will take x as an argument and return all pairs of integers that add up to x.

E.g. calling `find_factors(5)` will return:

```
[0, 5]
[1, 4]
[2, 3]
```

Comment: ^^ Now that I read your question again, it looks like you were interested in finding a single (random) pair only. As @mozway pointed out -- you may need all combinations, so my code will help you get them.

Comment: Much better approach than the original one (+1), still one could do even better by directly generating the pairs of numbers that add up to 100. (100+0, 99+1, 98+2...) without **any** test ;)

Comment: Without the "while true" it only gives me 1 output. I want a list of outputs but I don't want to print dublicate pairs.

Comment: My code above will return all pairs, without duplicates (that's why I added the i <= x-i condition).

Comment: @Mr.Green `pairs = [(i, 100-i) for i in range(51)]` that's it.

Comment: @mozway -- we may want to replace 100 with a generic x: [(i, x-i) for i in range(int(x/2+1))]

Comment: `x // 2 + 1`, or `x // 2 + x%2` if we want to avoid 50 + 50 (not two different numbers)

Comment: @mozway It's not specifically 100, but any input that a user writes. There has to be a prompt that asks the user to input any number.

Comment: @Mozway found it ! x = int(input('Input a number'))
for i in range(x):
     if i <= x-i: 
         print([i,x-i])

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly why avoid `50+50`? @Mr.Green wants to avoid duplicate pairs, e.g. `(40,60)` and `(60,40)`.

Comment: @Mr.Green No, use `pairs = [(i, 100-i) for i in range(x//2+1)]`, the test is useless

Comment: I guess so... but I don't know for sure whether he want pairs of unique numbers, or just unique pairs. Anyway, the `//` (int division) was the important bit.

Comment: @Mr.Green `pairs = [(i, x-i) for i in range(x//2+1)]` is the final answer, thanks everyone for the collab!

Answer (score 0):

`while True` means "repeat forever", you have to put and end to the loop:

```
import random

target_number = int(input('Input a number and we will return a list of two numbers that equate to this number'))

r1 = range(1,target_number)
r2 = range(1,target_number)

cont = True
while cont:
    for i in range(24):
        num1 = random.choice(r1)
        num2 = random.choice(r2)
        if num1 + num2 == target_number:
            print(f"solved: {num1}+{num2} = {target_number}")
            cont = False
```

Comment: I have a list of possible numbers adding to eg: 100, but most repeat themselves at least 15 times, the same  31+69 = 100. How to only have 1 (31+69 =100) ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

use **break** as soon as you find numbers with a sum of target_number in if statement.Otherwise this while loop will run forever.